Hot reload not working on webpack 5.91.0 and webpack-dev-server 5.0.4
After updating webpack from version 4.46.0 to version 5.91.0, hot reload stopped working (not to be confused with live reload).
Previously, the hot loader worked thanks to the library @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin.
webpack.config.js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

require('dotenv').config();

const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin');

// paths
const SOURCE = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const SINK = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
const PUBLIC = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');
const MODULES = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
const PFX = path.join(__dirname, '/certificates/development.pfx');
const APPICONS = path.join(__dirname, '/electron/icons');

// variables
const analyzeBundle = process.argv.indexOf('-a') >= 0;
const isProd = process.argv.indexOf('-p') >= 0 || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const HOST = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const HTML_OPTIONS = Object.assign(
  {},
  {
    inject: true,
    template: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/index.ejs'),
    favicon: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/favicon.ico'),
  },
  isProd
    ? {
        minify: {
          removeComments: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeRedundantAttributes: true,
          useShortDoctype: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
          keepClosingSlash: true,
          minifyJS: true,
          minifyCSS: true,
          minifyURLs: true,
        },
      }
    : undefined
);

module.exports = (env) => {
  const defaultLanguage = env && env.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE ? env.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE : 'en';
  const copyrightText = env && env.COPYRIGHT_TEXT ? env.COPYRIGHT_TEXT : '© Copyright placeholder';
  let productName = env && env.PRODUCT_NAME;
  let productEdition = env && env.PRODUCT_EDITION;
  const isElectronMode = env.PACKAGE_MODE === 'electron';

  if (!productEdition) {
    productEdition = productName ? '' : 'Develop';
  }
  if (!productName) {
    productName = 'ProductName';
  }
  let product = productName;
  if (productEdition !== '') {
    product += ` ${productEdition}`;
  }

  return {
    mode: !isProd ? 'development' : 'production',
    context: SOURCE,
    entry: {
      app: ['./index.tsx'],
      vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'lodash', 'webrtc-adapter', '@mui/material', '@mui/icons-material', '@mui/styles', 'reflect-metadata'],
    },
    output: {
      pathinfo: !isProd,
      filename: 'static/js/[name].[hash:8].bundle.js',
      chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[hash:8].bundle.js',
      path: SINK,
      publicPath: isElectronMode ? './' : '/',
      clean: true,
    },
    optimization: {
      moduleIds: 'named',
      minimize: true,
      minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
          minify: TerserPlugin.swcMinify,
          parallel: false,
          include: SOURCE,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          terserOptions: {
            sourceMap: !isProd,
          },
        }),
      ],
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        cacheGroups: {
          vendor: {
            chunks: 'initial',
            name: 'vendor',
            test: 'vendor',
            enforce: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    target: !isProd ? 'web' : 'browserslist',
    devtool: isProd ? 'source-map' : 'inline-cheap-module-source-map',
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@mui/styles': path.join(MODULES, '/@mui/styles'),
        '@App': SOURCE,
        Actions: path.join(SOURCE, '/actions/'),
        API: path.join(SOURCE, '/api/'),
        Common: path.join(SOURCE, '/common/'),
        Enums: path.join(SOURCE, '/enums/'),
        Factories: path.join(SOURCE, '/factories/'),
        Models: path.join(SOURCE, '/models/'),
        Reducers: path.join(SOURCE, '/reducers/'),
        Sagas: path.join(SOURCE, '/sagas/'),
        Selectors: path.join(SOURCE, '/selectors/'),
        Services: path.join(SOURCE, '/services/'),
        View: path.join(SOURCE, '/view/'),
        Translations: path.join(SOURCE, '/translations/'),
        Store: path.join(SOURCE, '/store/'),
      },
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      modules: [SOURCE, 'node_modules'],
      fallback: {
        url: false,
        crypto: false,
      },
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          exclude: MODULES,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'ts-loader',
              options: {
                compilerOptions: {
                  exclude: ['node_modules', 'src/__tests__'],
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        { enforce: 'pre', test: /\.js$/, loader: 'source-map-loader' },
        {
          test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|ogg|mp3|wav)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                name: 'static/media/[name].[ext]',
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
              options: {
                hmr: !isProd,
                reloadAll: true,
              },
            },
            'css-loader',
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(sa|sc)ss$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
              options: {
                hmr: !isProd,
                reloadAll: true,
              },
            },
            'css-loader',
            'postcss-loader',
            'sass-loader',
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'static/css/[name].[hash:8].css',
        chunkFilename: 'static/css/[id].[hash:8].css',
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin(HTML_OPTIONS),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: PUBLIC,
            to: SINK,
            globOptions: {
              ignore: ['index.ejs', 'manifest.json'],
            },
          },
          {
            from: path.resolve(PUBLIC, 'manifest.json'),
            to: path.resolve(SINK, 'manifest.json'),
            transform(content) {
              let manifest = JSON.parse(content);

              manifest['name'] = `${product} Web Client`;
              manifest['short_name'] = product;

              return JSON.stringify(manifest, null, 2);
            },
          },
          {
            from: APPICONS,
            to: path.join(SINK, '/icons'),
            toType: 'dir',
          },
        ],
      }),
      new WorkboxPlugin.InjectManifest({
        swSrc: path.join(__dirname, '/serviceWorker/service-worker.js'),
        maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 50 * 1024 * 1024,
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE': JSON.stringify(defaultLanguage),
        'process.env.COPYRIGHT_TEXT': JSON.stringify(copyrightText),
        'process.env.PRODUCT': JSON.stringify(product),
      }),
      analyzeBundle && new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
      !isProd && new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      !isProd && new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),
    ].filter(Boolean),
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 600,
      poll: 3000,
      ignored: [MODULES],
    },
    devServer: {
      watchFiles: SOURCE,
      liveReload: false,
      hot: true,
      static: {
        watch: false,
        staticOptions: {
          contentBase: PUBLIC,
        },
      },
      compress: true,
      devMiddleware: {
        publicPath: '/',
      },
      historyApiFallback: true,
      host: HOST,
      port: PORT,
      server: {
        type: 'https',
        options: {
          pfx: fs.readFileSync(PFX),
        },
      },
      client: {
        progress: true,
        logging: 'none',
        overlay: {
          warnings: false,
          errors: true,
        },
      },
    },
  };
};

package.json
{
  "name": "product_name1.0.0",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "electron/main.js",
  "productName": "ProductName",
  "description": "ProductName Description",
  "author": {
    "name": "Company placeholder",
    "email": "company@mail.xyz"
  },
  "homepage": ".",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.14",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.137",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.14",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.15.14",
    "@mui/x-data-grid-pro": "^6.19.3",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.19.3",
    "@mui/x-license-pro": "^6.10.2",
    "@mui/x-tree-view": "^6.17.0",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.11",
    "@types/leaflet": "1.7.9",
    "@types/leaflet-editable": "^1.2.4",
    "@types/react-dnd": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "@types/react-leaflet": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react-leaflet-markercluster": "^3.0.4",
    "@types/resize-observer-browser": "0.1.7",
    "again": "0.0.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "class-validator": "0.11.0",
    "classnames": "^2.5.1",
    "cross-env": "7.0.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "dnd-core": "^16.0.1",
    "file-saver": "2.0.5",
    "history": "4.10.1",
    "inversify": "^6.0.2",
    "inversify-inject-decorators": "3.1.0",
    "leaflet": "1.7.1",
    "leaflet-editable": "1.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-dnd": "10.0.2",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "10.0.2",
    "react-dnd-touch-backend": "10.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-intl": "^6.6.4",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
    "react-leaflet-editable": "^0.2.2",
    "react-leaflet-markercluster": "^3.0.0-rc1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-refresh": "^0.14.0",
    "react-resize-detector": "^7.1.2",
    "react-router": "5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.22.5",
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-first-history": "^5.2.0",
    "redux-saga": "1.1.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.2",
    "reselect": "^5.1.0",
    "tss-react": "^4.9.6",
    "typeface-roboto": "^1.1.13",
    "validator": "^13.11.0",
    "webrtc-adapter": "^9.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean:all": "npm run clean:build && npm run clean:modules && npm run clean:electron",
    "clean:build": "npx rimraf build",
    "clean:modules": "npx rimraf package-lock.json node_modules",
    "clean:electron": "npx rimraf dist",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--openssl-legacy-provider --max-old-space-size=4096\" webpack-dev-server --mode development --env PACKAGE_MODE=web --progress --color --open",
    "start:no-open": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--openssl-legacy-provider --max-old-space-size=4096\" webpack-dev-server --mode development --env PACKAGE_MODE=electron --progress --color",
    "prebuild": "npm run lint:fix",
    "ci-build": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--openssl-legacy-provider --max-old-space-size=4096\"  webpack --mode production --env PACKAGE_MODE=web --display-error-details --display-cached",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--openssl-legacy-provider --max-old-space-size=4096\" webpack --mode production --progress --env PACKAGE_MODE=web  --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
    "build:electron": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--openssl-legacy-provider --max-old-space-size=4096\" webpack --mode production --env PACKAGE_MODE=electron --progress --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
    "ci-build:electron": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"--openssl-legacy-provider --max-old-space-size=4096\" webpack --mode production --env PACKAGE_MODE=electron --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
    "build:analyze": "webpack --mode production --progress --colors --display-error-details --display-cached -a",
    "test": "jest --detectOpenHandles --logHeapUsage",
    "test:watch": "jest --detectOpenHandles --watch",
    "test:prod": "npm run lint:fix && npm run test -- --no-cache",
    "test:gui": "majestic --app",
    "ci-test": "jest --detectOpenHandles --env=jsdom --collectCoverage",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{ts,tsx}\" --config .eslintrc.json",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "prettier:base": "prettier \"src/**/*.{ts,tsx}\"",
    "prettier:check": "npm run prettier:base -- --list-different",
    "prettier:write": "npm run prettier:base -- --write --list-different",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "electron:start": "concurrently  \"npm run start:no-open\" \"wait-on https://localhost:3001 && electron . \"",
    "electron:build-deb": "electron-builder build --linux --publish never",
    "electron:build-win": "electron-builder build --win --publish never",
    "electron:rebuild-win": "npm run build:electron && electron-builder build --win --publish never"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
      "post-commit": "git update-index --again"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{ts,tsx}": [
      "npm run prettier:write",
      "npm run lint:fix",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.24.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.24.3",
    "@cfaester/enzyme-adapter-react-18": "^0.7.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.1.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "9.4.0",
    "@types/classnames": "2.2.9",
    "@types/enzyme": "3.10.5",
    "@types/file-saver": "2.0.6",
    "@types/google-maps": "3.2.1",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.39.2",
    "@types/history": "4.7.5",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.14",
    "@types/jsdom": "12.2.4",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.149",
    "@types/mocha": "10.0.5",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.6",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.67",
    "@types/react-color": "3.0.1",
    "@types/react-hot-loader": "4.1.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.7",
    "@types/react-resize-detector": "4.2.0",
    "@types/react-router": "5.1.4",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.1.3",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "@types/react-virtualized": "9.21.8",
    "@types/redux": "3.6.0",
    "@types/redux-logger": "3.0.7",
    "@types/redux-mock-store": "1.0.2",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.18.4",
    "@types/webrtc": "0.0.26",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.62.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.62.0",
    "autoprefixer": "9.7.4",
    "babel-core": "6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.7.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "concurrently": "8.2.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^12.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "electron": "26.3.0",
    "electron-builder": "24.6.4",
    "enzyme": "3.11.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "3.4.4",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "6.10.0",
    "eslint-config-react": "1.1.7",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.3.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
    "husky": "4.2.3",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "jest-dom": "4.0.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "25.1.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "1.0.1",
    "jest-enzyme": "7.1.2",
    "jsdom": "16.1.0",
    "lint-staged": "10.0.7",
    "majestic": "1.6.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.9.0",
    "mock-browser": "0.92.14",
    "mock-socket": "9.0.3",
    "npm-force-resolutions": "0.0.3",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "postcss-loader": "^8.1.1",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "react-dnd-test-backend": "10.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "react-testing-library": "8.0.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "1.5.4",
    "redux-saga-test-plan": "4.0.0-rc.3",
    "rimraf": "5.0.5",
    "sass-loader": "^14.1.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.10",
    "testcafe": "1.8.1",
    "ts-jest": "26.5.4",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "10.6.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.4",
    "wait-on": "7.0.1",
    "web-audio-test-api": "0.5.2",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.10.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "",
    "productName": "Product name",
    "copyright": "2023 Company placeholder",
    "win": {
      "icon": "/build/icons/appIcon-256.png",
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "nsis",
          "arch": [
            "x64"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "deb",
        "rpm"
      ],
      "icon": "build/icons"
    },
    "deb": {},
    "rpm": {},
    "files": [
      "build",
      "electron",
      "!node_modules"
    ],
    "extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "build/static/media",
        "to": "static/media"
      }
    ],
    "extends": null
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}

index.tsx
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import 'typeface-roboto';

import 'react-virtualized/styles.css';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import './index.css';

import { ElectronApiInit } from './electron/ElectronApi';
import { loadRootState } from './store/AppStateStore/AppStateStore';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import { IRootState } from './store/IRootState';
import App from './view/App';

const state: IRootState = loadRootState();
const history = createBrowserHistory();
const store = configureStore(history, state);

ElectronApiInit();

const render = (): void => {
  ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App history={history} />
    </Provider>
  );
};

if (module.hot !== undefined) {
  module.hot.accept('./view/App', render);
}

service-worker.js
workbox.skipWaiting();
workbox.clientsClaim();
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute('/index.html');

workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(
  self.__precacheManifest.concat([
    'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Serif+Pro:400,700',
    'https://unpkg.com/react@16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js',
    'https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js',
    'https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.0.0/umd/react-router-dom.min.js',
  ])
);

By the way, when building the project, a warning appears:
WARNING in InjectManifest has been called multiple times, perhaps due to running webpack in --watch mode. The precache manifest generated after the first call may be inaccurate! Please see https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1790 for more information.
Maybe this will somehow affect the hot reload?
What was done:
Set the devServer.hot property to true.
Set the devServer.liveReload property to false.
Connected the webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() plugin (although it is no longer required in webpack version 5, as setting hot to true is sufficient).
Changed the index.tsx file to call module.hot.accept().

I'm joining the problem.
I'm trying to upgrade to webpack-dev-server@5.0.4 and I get peer dependencies issues with @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.5.11

After a year that @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin was untouched, the package is now ready for usage to adopt the peer dependencies :)
version 0.5.13 (28 Apr 2024) was released.
npm i @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@latest

then
npm i webpack-dev-server@5.0.4

thanks @pmmmwh
